# Visual simulation of gravitational lensing

Tags: gravitational-waves, simulations, gravitational-lensing, visualization

Is there a way to generate an accurate visual computer simulation of gravitational lensing?

Comment: Have you looked at the text, Schneider, Ehlers & Falco (1992) Gravitational lenses, Springer?  This is an older book, last 80s, but still relevant from a theoretical point of view.  It really boils down to ray optics.  If you understand the effective lens created by the stess - energy tensor then you can apply ordinary optics.

Comment: Will look into that paper, thanks.

Comment: It's a text book, part of the Springer-Verlag astrophysics library.  You may also be interested in Unruh and Visser's work on acoustic analogs of black holes.  It might sound off topic (puns intended) but the connection (more puns) might help you to see how the metric tensor and its derivative (connection and curvature) create and effective refractive index.  I actually used these equations to develop ray trace software for acoustic lensing.

Comment: Thanks, will look into the book (not an article) and Unruh and Visser's work on acoustic analogs of black holes. Please take a look at this post: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/gravitational-wave-interference-graphical-computer-simulation.969881/